How to find an app that has storage permission
recently the old android phone of a friend was acting up (slower than usual, the keyboard was not working properly) so she searched around and found a list of a lot of things that had storage permissions, something called aire.Into_the_fog:

This list is even longer, 20+ items.
She said those items were there for not long since she looks around her apps from time to time. We are not sure what installed those and we can't find them in the file explorer or in the list of installed apps, and the only risky app she has is a popular fork of tachiyomi (maybe that's the cause?).
There are 0 results when I search aire.Into_the_fog on the internet which only worries me more.
I recommended her to reset her phone, but are there other alternatives to delete whatever is installing that?
Not sure if this info will help but her phone is a samsung galaxy s7 edge using Android 8.0

If you google it, you can see likely candidates.  Explore those apps.  Or just remove the apps installed in the last dew months.
